# Ros::ok() return true with dead roscore in node started as root

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, rosmaster, root

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to kill my node started as root.
In my case, my node need to be started as root to access some hardware (gpio).
So I added `sudo -E` as a launch-prefix to my node.

When I ctrl+c my launchfile, the roscore died but node my node (probably due to the fact that the signal SIGTERM is not forwarded to program started as root). But I was expecting `ros::ok()` to return false or even `ros::isShuttingDown()` to return true, but no.

In this case as a normal user or as root `rosnode list` return `ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!`, so the master is dead but my node doesn't know about this.

```
<launch>
  <node name="test_node" pkg="test_pkg" type="test_node" launch-prefix="sudo -E" />
</launch>
```

and a simple node to test it:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "test_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::NodeHandle nh_p("~");
    ros::Rate rate(10);
    while (ros::ok()) {
        ros::spinOnce();
        // do stuff
        rate.sleep();
        std::cerr<<"ros is ok"<<std::endl;
        if(ros::isShuttingDown())
          std::cerr<<"shutdown is called"<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cerr<<"program exit properly"<<std::endl;
    //free acess to hardware
    return 0;
```

Maybe this way is not the good one to kill a node started as root, I am open to any suggestion.
Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296295/ros::ok()-return-true-with-dead-roscore-in-node-started-as-root/) by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 312 on 2018-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-07-05**:
my suggestion would be to allow non-root users to acces the GPIOs. What platform are you using? You can do this either via udev, by adding yourself to a specific group (e.g. dialout) or by making the GPIO world-read-writeable. So I'd suggest one or two.
About your problem, I cannot help there.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-05**:\

> But I was expecting `ros::ok()` to return false or even `ros::isShuttingDown()` to return true

`ros::ok()` returns whether the process local ROS objects are in an OK (enough) state. Not whether the master is still up.

`isShuttingDown()` returns whether the local node has been requested ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-05**:
.. to stop (using `rosnode kill ..` fi, or by a `roslaunch` server instance after `ctrl+c`).

The problem here is that a regular user cannot ask processes from other users to terminate using signals, as it doesn't have the right permissions.

Does the node shutdown if you use `rosnode kill`?

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2018-07-05**:
@mgruhler I am using a raspberry pi 3 (Ubuntu ARM) and pigpio. And I haven't found any way to use pigpio without root.

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2018-07-05**:
@gvdhoorn thanks for the explaination I didn't knew about this.
rosnode kill return `ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!` as normal user or as root.
The only way I found to kill the process was to send a SIGTERM signal as root.
Maybe I could check if the master is still alive.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-07-05**:
@GuillaumeB there are many questions about GPIO and RPi on this site. Check out #q278090 and the link therein, or #q229435

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-05**:\

> rosnode kill return `ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!`

did you do this after you `ctrl+c`-ed everything already? If so, that would make sense.

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2018-07-05**:
Yes, after the `ctrl+c`.
I just tried the other way around and it worked. I can use `rosnode kill` before the `ctr+c`

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2018-07-05**:
A solution to my problem could be to start a node next to the one with sudo, catch the `ctrl+c` and call the `rosnode kill my_root_node`. But it sound ugly

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-06**:
Afaict from some of the Q&As that @mgruhler posted, it should be possible to use GPIO on RPis without `sudo`. That would immediately solve your problem.

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2018-07-08**:
Unfortunately, I could find anything about the lib I use `pigpio`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the node was started as root it was not possible for it to catch `ctrl+c`
I could use rosnode kill to kill the node but in my case I wanted the node to die after `ctrl+c`ed my Launchfile.

So I had two options:

- Find a way to run [Pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) with a non-root user
- Find a way to kill the node started as root with the `ctrl+c` of the launchfile

I didn't find any way to use Pigpio without root, so I went for the second option.

I created a second node in the same package that was publishing a topic (with an empty msg) and added it to the launchfile (without sudo for this one).
In the node started as Root I added a subscriber for this topic. And if I am not receiving anything for 1 second I just exit the node, thus releasing the access to GPIO.

---

Originally posted by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) with karma: 312 on 2018-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0